# cPickle.load( ) error

Tags: python, linux, pickle

I am working with cPickle for the purpose to convert the structure data into datastream format and pass it to the library. The thing i have to do is to read file contents from manually written file name "targetstrings.txt" and convert the contents of file into that format which Netcdf library needs in the following manner,

Note: targetstrings.txt contains latin characters

```
op=open("targetstrings.txt",'rb')
targetStrings=cPickle.load(op)
```

The Netcdf library take the contents as strings.
While loading a file it stuck with the following error,

```
cPickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'A'.
```

Please tell me how can I rectify this error, I have googled around but did not find an appropriate solution.

Any suggestions,

Comment: How is `targetstrings.txt` generated?

Comment: targetstrings.txt is a mannualy generated file. I want to read contents from this file and pass those contents to library

Comment: "The Netcdf library take the contents as strings" you mean, Netcdf wants as an input a list of strings, each corresponding to a line of your input file?

Comment: yes, it does require the same

Answer (score 2):

pickle is not for reading/writing generic text files, but to serialize/deserialize Python objects to file. If you want to read text data you should use [Python's usual IO functions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

```
with open('targetstrings.txt', 'r') as f:
    fileContent = f.read()
```

---

If, as it seems, the library just wants to have a list of strings, taking each line as a list element, you just have to do:

```
with open('targetstrings.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines=[l for l in f]
# now in lines you have the lines read from the file
```

Comment: Yes, i know this but I am sorry i did not convey my problem properly. Actually I have read the file contents and wants to pass those contents to library. I came to know that cPickle can convert the format of read contents of file into that which library requires. i did the same but stucked with the error as I mentioned above.

Comment: You should edit your original question and specify all the context (which library, what format it expects, what is stored in the .txt, ...), otherwise you won't get any meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

As stated - Pickle is not meant to be used in this way.
If you need to manually edit complex Python objects taht are to be read and passed as Python objects to another function, there are plenty of other formats to use - for example XML, JSON, Python files themselves. Pickle uses a Python specific protocol, that while note being binary (in the version 0 of the protocol), and not changing across Python versions, is not meant for this, and is not even the recomended method to record Python objects for persistence or comunication (although it can be used for those purposes).